# Node/Express — req.query.token // udefined going to localhost:3000/?token=foobar

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, jwt

I'm trying to parse a URL in an Express backend but when I go to a url like `localhost:3000/token=myJwtToken` I get `undefined` for req.query.token in my `authJwt.verifyToken` middleware in the backend.

In my React App.js, I'm hitting the below endpoint where I need to verify a token in the URL as a param / query string with a secret shared by sending and receiving parties:

```
const req = {
  url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/verify',
  method: 'GET',
};
```

In my backend I have this route:

```
module.exports = function (app) {
  app.get(
    '/api/verify',
    [authJwt.verifyToken], // verify token in URL middleware
    galleryController.loadGallery, // proceed to gallery
  );
};
```

My verifyToken auth middleware is thus:

```
verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
  let token = req.query.token;
  console.log(token); // undefined
  console.log(req.params); // {}

  if (!token) {
    console.log('NO TOKEN!!!');
    return res.status(401).send({
      message: 'Unauthorized!',
    });
  }

  jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET, (err, decoded) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(`Error: ${err}`);
      return res.status(401).send({
        message: `Error: ${err}`,
      });
    }
    console.log('success!', decoded.token);
    next();
  });
};
```

Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`localhost:3000/token=myJwtToken` is an (invalid) path, not a query parameter

`localhost:3000/api/verify?token=myJwtToken` will return a query parameter with key token and value myJwtToken

Comment: This makes total sense... I need to send the full URL from the frontend to the backend. I know this is a dumb question, but can't I parse a full URL (with query strings/params) from the backend just by hitting "/" from frontend... or can the backend only ever know what the front end sends it?

Comment: no such thing as dumb questions when we're learning. There are three ways to pass data to the backend in this way -- you can either use a path parameter, like if you were doing GET /api/<USERID>/data -- you can use a query parameter like GET /api/data?userid=1234&content=data -- or you can use the body of the request to pass more significant data, like POST /api/data with a body of { "userid": "1234", "content": "data", "date": "03/03/2020" }